# Linq OrderBy Count In linked list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I've been struggling for a while now. All I am trying to do is OrderBy a list of records by the Count() of a 3rd child in the relationship tree. I will try and draw the 3 tables involved below, sorry if I don't use the stackoverflow standards:

Websites ----> Roles ----> Permissions

In words, a website can have more than 1 Roles, a role can have more than 1 Permissions. So it's a 1-to-many.

When I try something like:

```
List<Website> websites = Model.WebsiteOptions.OrderBy( o => o.Roles.OrderBy( r => r.RolePermissions.Count ) ).ToList();
```

I get an error that's clear enough:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

but I still don't know how I can either way order Websites by the number of Permissions each Role has...What I want is for websites that have Roles with the most Permissions to come first.

Please does anyone know or show me some guidance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because in your `OrderBy` you should specify how to order the collection - meaning supplying an object that implements `IComparable`.

In your implementation you are actually supplying another collection which is sorted (this is irrelevant though). An `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't implement `IComparable<IEnumerable<T>>` but just `IComparable<T>` - it can compare 2 "simple" items but not two collections. (Will you do it by number of elements?.. biggest element? It is generic so what does biggest even mean.....)

Try something like:

```
List<Website> websites = Model.WebsiteOptions.OrderBy( o => o.Roles.Max( r => r.RolePermissions.Count ) ).ToList();
```

This will order your `Website`s by the option that has the highest RolePermissions count

Comment: thanks a lot. So I modified your solution to something like to suppress an error and ordering the list from Max -to- Least:
`List<Website> websites = Model.WebsiteOptions.OrderByDescending( o => ( o.Roles.Any() ? o.Roles.Max( r => r.RolePermissions.Count ) : 0 ) ).ToList();`. It turned out some websites didn't have roles assigned yet, and some roles didn't have permissions yet...

Comment: Nice catching of the `.Any()`. BTW - make sure `o.Roles` isn't `null` either

Comment: It's straight from db by Entity Framework (linq-sql) so it'll always come as an Empty `ICollection` so I guess I am covered for `null`

Comment: Also you can check `.DefaultIfEmpty` extension method instead of having that ` : ?` - might look a bit cleaner in your eyes

Comment: Yes true that, after research I found I could use the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` but initial initiative got me doing it with the `.Any()` function...